# How to get Option Set Description field in MSCRM

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I've tried to find where Option Set descriptions are stored in CRM's database. After research on the internet I've found that Option Set data is stored in the  `StringMap` SQL table but this table doesn't contain description Field I want.

Does anyone know where Option Set descriptions are stored stored in CRM's SQL database? Below is a screenshot highlighting the field value I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Label FROM [LocalizedLabelView] llv
join [AttributePicklistValueView] apvv on llv.ObjectId = apvv.AttributePicklistValueId
join [OptionSetView] osw on apvv.OptionSetId = osw.OptionSetId
join [AttributeView] aw on osw.OptionSetId = aw.OptionSetId
where aw.Name = 'fieldname' and llv.ObjectColumnName = 'Description'
```

This works for both global and non-global option sets, you just have to put as fieldname the name of the attribute on the entity (not a name of global option set). Of course to handle only global option sets you will not need the last join, simply do osw.Name = 'globaloptionsetname'

Comment: Thank you, this is query I want

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT l.Label
 FROM MetadataSchema.LocalizedLabel l
 LEFT JOIN MetadataSchema.AttributePicklistValue ap ON l.ObjectId = ap.AttributePicklistValueId
 LEFT JOIN MetadataSchema.OptionSet os ON os.OptionSetId = ap.OptionSetId
 WHERE l.ObjectColumnName = 'Description' AND os.Name = '<OPTIONSET_NAME>' AND ap.Value = <OPTIONSET_VALUE>
```

There are two parameters in the above script that you need to modify:

- `<OPTIONSET_NAME>` must be replaced with the schema name of your optionset and prefixed with the entity's schema name. For example, if your optionset is called *new_businessTypes* and it's on the *account* entity, then `<OPTIONSET_NAME>` would be replaced with `'account_new_businesstypes'`.
- `<OPTIONSET_VALUE>` must be replaced with the integer value of the option you're looking for. In your example screenshot, that value is 2.

Comment: does this work for global and non-global optionsets ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've try your query but I don't have ObjectColumnName = 'Description' Then I filter with my OptionSet_Name but It's doesn't exists I think because your query only work with Global optionSet right ?